# How can I get my phone to find contacts by name *or* company name?

Tags: contacts

I have an HTC Droid Incredible running Android 2.2 (Froyo). I keep my contacts in GMail, and they are automatically synced to my phone. The problem is, my phone's "Search People" app seems to search by business name/organization *only* if no contact name has been entered.

Is there any way to trick the phone into searching by either name *or* business name/organization when both of these fields are in use?

Alternatively, is there a better app for looking up contacts than the "Search People" app that came with the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using google search, works flawlesly on my magic to look for contacts in any way i like , you might need to update latest version from the market

Comment: +1. You're right...that does work. I can't understand why it would do a much smarter search than the "Search People" app, but it does. The only thing I don't like about it is that you have to select People from the drop-down menu. I'd like to be able to set up a shortcut so I can do a search with just one click from the home screen, but the shortcut ends up being People Search rather than Google People Search. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: you can also add the google search widget and configure it to search in contacts by default

Answer (score -1):

Go for [Truecaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.truecaller&hl=en) app. It's the best app for finding name by phone number.

Comment: Why? What does it make so special? And is there a link you can provide to find the app?